# PHP echo returns error if using saveXML()?

Tags: php, xml

I am using PHP to generate a XML and display on my browser. I have the following code:

```php
<?php

header("content-type:application/xml;    charset=ISO-8859-15"); 
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
// we want a nice output
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$root = $doc->createElement('book');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

$title = $doc->createElement('title');
$title = $root->appendChild($title);

$text = $doc->createTextNode('This is the title');
$text = $title->appendChild($text);

//echo "Saving all the document:\n";
//echo $doc->saveXML()."\n";

echo "Saving only the title part:\n";
echo $doc->saveXML($title);

?>
```

If I comment out `echo "Saving only the title part:\n";`, it generates the XML to me in my browser without any problem, but if I try to add this `echo "Saving only the title part:\n";` before `echo $doc->saveXML($title);`, it will give me the following error in my browser :

> This page contains the following errors:
> error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
> Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Does anybody knows why? Is there a way to display a string before printing out the XML in my browser?

Comment: By echoing out non-xml at the start of the output, your browser isn't going to like it. Thus the error. Basically you have broken the proper format of an xml file by echoing garbage outside of it.

Comment: I agree with @IncredibleHat, if you really want to output text first, maybe change the headers so the browser doesn't expect xml. eg, header("content-type: text/plain");

Comment: This also happens when php spits out a warning or notice too, it can break the strictly formatted content expectations. Have to be careful!

Comment: Thanks for all your  comment. even I do the following, it doesn't work. header("content-type:text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15"); 
echo "Saving only the title part:\n";
header("content-type:application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-15"); 
echo $doc->saveXML($title);What can I do so I can echo the string without error? It seems that somehow a [] is added at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have set your documents content type to `application/xml`, so the browser is expecting all content to be in the form of XML.

To get the above code to work, change the content type to `text/plain`

The following code works (tested on my machine):

```
header("content-type:text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15");
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');

$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$root = $doc->createElement('book');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

$title = $doc->createElement('title');
$title = $root->appendChild($title);

echo "Saving only the title part:\n";
echo $doc->saveXML($title);
```